# Redirected to localhost:8080 after JDBC authentication in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, http-authentication

I have a few endpoints which I've secured using Spring Security JDBC authentication. When I hit my endpoint, browser prompts me for username and password. After success, Spring forwards me to `localhost:8080` by showing 404 error. I know it's a success because if I enter invalid username and password, I get a error message on the login form page itself.

```java
@Autowired 
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource).
    usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from user where username=?").
    authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/getMessages/").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/api/getFollowings/").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/api/getFollowers/").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/api/getFollowings/").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/api/follow/").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/api/unfollow/").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/").permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

This is one of my endpoints:

[image]

[After hitting the endpoint, I'm prompted for username and password][2]

[After entering the username and password, I'm being sent to localhost:8080 which shows 404][3]

Comment: What URL did you call and what do you expect after a successful authentication?

Comment: I called localhost:8080/api/getMessages along with the GET parameter. I want that after authentication, I should be redirected to the same url.

Comment: Did you get the browser login dialog (HTTP basic) or a login page (form login)?

Comment: a login page which I didn't create.

Comment: Did you annotate your configuration with `@EnableWebSecurity`? Or did add an `@Order` annotation? BTW: Why do you use `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`, although you configured a form login? That's makes no sense.

Comment: I added SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS because I want to secure each end point per request. I don't want user's credentials to be saved or cookied for any request. Each request should be treated as new, if authentication succeeds, endpoint should be hit, if not, error.